# OpenStreetMap: HTTP Basic Authentication with Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, basic-authentication, openstreetmap

I'm trying to write some [notes](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Notes) via a Python script.

OSM API should support HTTP Basic Authentication.

By following the example that I found on the Python documentation, I wrote this script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import urllib.request
import urllib.parse

url = 'http://api.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/notes'
username = 'Stemby'
password = input('password > ')


# Create an OpenerDirector with support for Basic HTTP Authentication...
auth_handler = urllib.request.HTTPBasicAuthHandler()
auth_handler.add_password(realm='Web Password',
        uri=url, user=username,
        passwd=password)
opener = urllib.request.build_opener(auth_handler)
# ...and install it globally so it can be used with urlopen.
urllib.request.install_opener(opener)


def send_note(lat, lon, text):
    data = dict(lat=lat, lon=lon, text=text)
    urllib.request.urlopen(url, urllib.parse.urlencode(data).encode('utf8'))


lat = input('lat > ')
lon = input('lon > ')
text = input('text > ')

send_note(lat, lon, text)
```

I found the realm [here](http://lists.openstreetmap.org/pipermail/dev/2011-January/021701.html).

In this way I can create new notes, but these notes are anonymous; so the authentication doesn't work.

Can you help me?

I'm using Python 3.2.4 on Debian Jessie.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you know about [requests](http://python-requests.org)?

Comment: No, I don't.I will try it. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Solved by using [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/). On Debian the package name is "python3-requests".

Here is my script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import requests

url = 'http://api.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/notes'
username = input('username > ')
password = input('password > ')

def send_note(lat, lon, text):
    data = dict(lat=lat, lon=lon, text=text)
    requests.post(url, data=data, auth=(username, password))

lat = input('lat > ')
lon = input('lon > ')
text = input('text > ')

send_note(lat, lon, text)
```

Ciao!